# Ordering in sequelize by first model

Tags: sequelize.js

```
models.modelOne.findOne({
    attributes: [ 'id', 'name' ],
    where: { name },
    include: [
      {
        model: models.modelTwo,
        attributes: ['id', 'name'],
        where: {name: nameTwo},
        required: false
      }
    ],
    order: [
      [ ???? ]
    ]
});
```

How to order by model on 'id'? I need to order it by modelOne by 'id' in 'DESC'
If i do like

```
order: [
    [ 'id', 'DESC' ]
]
```

I get the error message:

> message: 'A column has been specified more than once in the order by
>   list. Columns in the order by list must be unique.'

Answer (score 0):

You have two `id` columns on your query, one from `modelOne` and another from `modelTwo`. Just remove the `id` from `modelTwo` `attributes` inside the `include` option.